# Makefile all target order

Tags: makefile

Does order in makefile all target matters ?

For eg. if I have -

```
all : target1 target2 target3
```

Does the order matters here i.e. will target2 be always executed after target3 ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The POSIX standard for `make` requires that `make` consider prerequisites in the order they were listed in the makefile.

So yes, in your example `make` is required to first try to build `target1`, then try to build `target2`, then try to build `target3`, then, if any of those targets were updated, it will try to run the recipe for `all` if one exists.

However, it's a bad idea to rely on this when you write your makefile.

First, what if someone runs `make target3` but you can't build `target3` until `target2` is complete?  Then `make target3` will not try to build `target2` because `make` doesn't know that it's needed.

Second, if you invoke `make -j` (parallel builds) then `make` can try to build `target1`, `target2`, and `target3` all at the same time.  If they rely on each other this will likely break things.

If you have a dependency relationship between two targets, you should tell `make` about it by declaring a prerequisite.  That way you know your build is reliable.